Issue with Creating RasterStack in Custom R Function build_vd_raster2
I am trying to write an R function, build_vd_raster2, to process spatial data and create a RasterStack of daily raster layers. The function is designed to split data by day, generate spatial linestrings for vessel tracks (based on their MMSI identifiers), intersect these tracks with a grid, and finally rasterize the results.
Here is my function:
build_vd_raster2 <- function(month) {
  # Split data into daily subsets
  list.imp <- month %>%
    split(as.Date(.$TIMESTAMP_UTC))
  
  # Process data for each day
  daily_rasters <- purrr::map(list.imp, function(day_data) {
    ves_split <- day_data %>% split(droplevels(.$MMSI))
    
    # Create linestrings for each vessel
    lines <- purrr::map(ves_split, function(vessel_data) {
      if (nrow(vessel_data) > 1) {
        # Validate and transform geometries
        vessel_data <- sf::st_make_valid(vessel_data)
        vessel_data <- sf::st_transform(vessel_data, crs = 3857)
        grid <- sf::st_transform(grid, crs = 3857)
        
        # Perform spatial operations
        vessel_data %>%
          dplyr::summarize(do_union = FALSE) %>%
          sf::st_cast("LINESTRING") %>%
          sf::st_intersection(grid) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(presence = 1)
      } else {
        sf::st_sf()  # Return an empty object for single-point MMSIs
      }
    }) %>% purrr::discard(~ nrow(.) == 0)  # Remove empty objects
    
    # Combine daily results
    if (length(lines) > 0) {
      combined_lines <- do.call(rbind, lines)
      grid_presence <- grid %>%
        dplyr::left_join(
          combined_lines %>%
            dplyr::group_by(cell) %>%
            dplyr::summarize(presence = sum(presence, na.rm = TRUE)),
          by = "cell"
        ) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(presence = ifelse(is.na(presence), 0, presence))
      
      # Rasterize
      raster::rasterize(
        grid_presence,
        r,
        field = "presence",
        background = 0
      )
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  # Create RasterStack
  daily_rasters <- purrr::keep(daily_rasters, ~ !is.null(.))
  raster_stack <- raster::stack(daily_rasters)
  
  return(raster_stack)
} 

What I’m trying to do:

Split data by day: I split my input dataset mes into daily subsets using the TIMESTAMP_UTC field.
Process vessel data: For each day, I split the data by MMSI (vessel identifier) and attempt to create a spatial linestring for each vessel’s trajectory. If a vessel has only one data point for a day, I skip it.
Spatial operations: The linestrings are intersected with a predefined spatial grid (grid), and a presence field is added to count the number of intersecting lines.
Rasterization: The resulting data is rasterized using the raster::rasterize() function.
Combine into a stack: Finally, I combine the daily rasters into a RasterStack for analysis.

The function is applied to each element of 'list' as follows:
daily.vd <- purrr::map(cargo.list, build_vd_raster2)

However, I am encountering the following issues:
Errors related to geometry validation or intersection operations in certain cases.
The rasterization step does not consistently produce the expected output, possibly due to issues with the input data structure.

I developed a similar function to perform the same task using points, which is considerably simpler:
  list.imp <- month %>%
    split(as.Date(.$TIMESTAMP_UTC))
  
  daily_ves <- purrr:::map(list.imp, function(x)
    x %>% split(droplevels(.$MMSI)) %>%
      map(~ raster::rasterize(x = .x, y = r, field=1, na.rm=F)) %>%
      raster::stack() %>%
      raster::stackApply(., indices = rep(1,nlayers(.)), 
                         fun = 'sum')
  )
  
  daily_ves.stack <- stack(daily_ves)
  
}


... possibly due to issues with the input data structure. Without a copy of your data, there is no way to definitively rule out all possible causes. Assuming cargo.list is your dataset, please run dput(cargo.list) and add the result to a codeblock as an edit to your question. It would be better to subset cargo.list before running dput(), just need the minimum amount of data required to see your function work once, and to fail once.
